# Send data from Serverside Nodejs to Client Side (Not on socket)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, socket.io

I'm looking for a way to send data from my socket, e.g.`example.com:8000` to my web server not on the socket `example.com/index.php.` I've been looking around at code, but I haven't found any answers. If you make sample code, could you display the `var x` which is = to 2 from Nodejs to the client?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

Comment: thats for android?

Comment: so whats your client ?

Comment: When i sead client, i ment client side javascript. Eg my website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using NodeJS as the server, then I recommend using this package:
[npm ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws), it's a super light Web Socket for server side.

Now, to your example:

**Server Side:**

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});
```

**Client side**

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/');
    socket.onopen = () => {
        console.log("I'm open!");
        socket.send('Sending from client');
    }
    socket.onmessage = (message) => {
        console.log('Received: ', message);
        console.log('Received Data: ', message.data);
    }
```

- You'll see a `console.log` on the server that says **"received: Sending from client"**
- You'll see two console.logs on the client saying:

  `Received:  MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "something", origin: 
             "ws://127.0.0.1:8080", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}`

  AND

  `Received Data:  something`

The data received *"something"* was emitted from the server on `ws.send('something');`, you can change that to a JSON type string and then parsing the `message.data` on the client with `JSON.parse(message.data)`

**NOTE:** On client, `WebSocket()` is native API, so you don't have to import anything, unlike the NodeJS server, where the NPM package is desirable.

You can actually test the client side though your developer console.